# Loop cut scaling works on all edges except the elected one

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm trying to scale down a loop cut I select. When I do the selection operation the scaling affects all the edges except for the one I clicked on to select the loop cut and I do not know why this happens. Any ideas? In the first picture you can see the loop with the selected edge and the scaling applied to it. The white line scales in length but does not move inwards towards the center of of the square. On the other image you can see the other side of the loop cut which is behaving as expected when scaled

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the Transform Pivot Point set to Active Element which causes the loop to scale around that Edge. Set it to Median Point on the dropdown and it should scale correctly.

[image]